# Подскажите пожалуйста почему по этому коду картинка не высвечивается.

Tags: html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML  4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Тег TABLE</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<p><img src="C:\Documents and Settings\Пользователь\Мои документы\Мои рисунки\безымянный.png" 
        alt="Адрес размещения изображения относительно текущего HTML-документа"></p>

 </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: *Ммм-да...* Проверьте, есть ли картинка по указанному в src адресу.

Comment: быть может сразу бросить верстать?

это

>C:\Documents and Settings\Пользователь\Мои документы\Мои рисунки\безымянный.png

и это 

>C:\Documents%20and%20Settings\Пользователь\Мои%20документы\Мои%20рисунки\bezimyann.png

разные вещи!

Читайте мануалы по верстке, никогда не подставляйте русские имена файлов ну и т.к.

Comment: Не советую использовать в названии изображений:

1. русские буквы  
2. пробелы  
3. путь на жестком диске

Иначе может случиться такой shit как у вас.

Answer (score 1):

```
<img src="file:///C:\Documents and Settings\Пользователь\Мои документы\Мои рисунки\безымянный.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Юмористы))
Можно сделать относительный путь от html файла. В латинице.